# How to disable same origin policy in Chrome 94?

Tags: google-chrome, same-origin-policy

For development purposes, I had a especially configured Google Chrome shortcut that allowed us to circumvent the same origin policy. This would in turn set a cookie with the result of the query to that endpoint, Anyway, the configured used to be as follows.

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-gpu --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\Users\joao.pereira\Documents\cors_user_data_dir"
```

However, as of Chrome 91, according to the release notes, the `SameSiteDefaultCookies` and `CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure` would be dropped come Chrome 94.

> Mar 18, 2021: The flags #same-site-by-default-cookies and
> #cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure have been removed from chrome://flags as of Chrome 91, as the behavior is now enabled by
> default. In Chrome 94, the command-line flag
> --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure
> will be removed.

And that's where we're at as Chrome 94 has arrived. With these dropped, I am currently unable to access the intended resources. Unfortunately, downgrading the Chrome version isn't an option either since the computer is controled by the organization. Setting another browser with a similiar configuration would work so suggestions in that regard are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may ask your System Admin to disable this feature by updating managed policies on your system (if you don't have control) for your browser as [mentioned here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList). See [How To Setup for Windows](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/windows-quick-start/)

You can whitelist all of your domains that you don't want to check for `SameSite` cookie policy.